# Can I get data on currently played tracks in a certain area through Spotify API

Tags: spotify, spotify-app

I've been looking through the API support section of the Spotify website for any way to see what everyone in, for instance, Amsterdam is listening to right now.

I did find [this](https://www.spotify.com/us/arts/serendipity/) web app that appears to do exactly that but it's from Spotify itself and I'm not sure if all developers can have access to the same data.

If anyone could point me in the right direction (even if it is letting me know it's impossible) that would be fantastic!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a Spotify's project using data that is not currently exposed through Spotify APIs.

The closest you can find is the [Charts API](http://charts.spotify.com/?object=tracks&rank=most_streamed&country=nl&windowtype=daily&date=latest) which can provide you with daily top charts by country.

Comment: Thanks! I thought as much, too bad :)